# Mapreduce similar movies

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

MapReduce:Find Similar Movies

After creating pairs of candidate similar movies how do i calculate the jaccard similarity between them, so that i found the similar movies?

e.g. userID, movie ID1, movie ID2 rating1, rating2

```
 1,      1        , 2         5      , 4
 2,      1        , 4         4      , 3
 3,      1        , 2         4      , 5
```

the table shows that movie1 and movie 2 are similar because they had been rated from 2 different users (user1 and user3) the similar rating.

Answer (score 0):

Read "Non-negative matrix factorization" in Wikipedia.

On MapReduce level: stochastic gradient descent is done my dividing the training set into subsets processed by reducers and then averaging parameters between subsets.

See Collaborative Filtering in Mahout for reference.